# Howto automatically open FITS images and tables with different apps from the Mac OS X Finder?

Tags: macos, file-browser, astronomy, fits

[FITS files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FITS) can contain several images (or more generally n-dimensional arrays) and tables.
Is there a way to automatically open images e.g. with the [ds9](http://hea-www.harvard.edu/RD/ds9) application and tables with the [TOPCAT](http://www.star.bris.ac.uk/~mbt/topcat/) application when I double-click the FITS file in the Mac OS X Finder?

I'm thinking of something like [FITS Explorer from AstroSoft](https://sites.google.com/site/astrosoftint/home/fits-explorer), but free and nicely integrated into the Mac (i.e. Finder, Quicklook).

If such a thing doesn't exist, what is your workflow for browsing and opening images and tables in FITS files?

Comment: Some people below mentioned my plugin: QLFits. But its address changed: http://www.onekilopars.ec/open-source/#qlfits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found [QLFits](http://softtenebraslux.com/qlfits/) which is a Mac OS X Finder QuickLook plugin that display some FITS  header info and an image simply by hitting SPACE after selecting a FITS file in the Finder.

The same guy wrote [FITSImporter](http://softtenebraslux.com/fitsimporter/):

> a Spotlight plugin that allow you make spotlight queries against dedicated FITS header keywords. It provides also additional information in the "Get Info" panel of the Finder (⌘-I).

Both are open source (GPL licence), the code is available on github: [QLFITS](https://github.com/SoftTenebrasLux/QLFits), [FITSImporter](https://github.com/SoftTenebrasLux/FITSImporter).

They are not perfect though (e.g. I didn't see a way to get at the different extensions in a multi-extension FITS file, although the description says there is; and you can't use QLFits to browse tables) and development seems to have stopped, but still well worth a try!

Answer (score 0):

Apart from recommending you QLFits, you could try to write an AppleScript application, or Automator action using any scripting language, which explored the FITS file, and sent table-based FITS to TOPCAT, and image-based FITS to DS9, and make that application the default for FITS files.